# Rotated table exceeds width of text block

Tags: tables, rotating

I have a table (code in the final) that is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. However, it is too wide. How can I solve that (fit to the width of (rotated) text block)? One solution could be to make the first 2 columns, multi-line columns but I'm not being succeeded in doing do.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Algorithm}}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Prediction Method}} & \multicolumn{15}{c|}{PH (min)}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{3-17} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{10}                                                                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{20}                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{30}                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{45}                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{60}                                                                \\ \cline{3-17} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RMSE} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R_{adj}^2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RMSE}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R_{adj}^2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RMSE}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R_{adj}^2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RMSE}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R_{adj}^2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RMSE}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Adj.~$r^2$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Naive}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.43} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.90}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13.40} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.69}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.82} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.45}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{21.53} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.16}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22.75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.00}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Linear Regression}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Direct}                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{34} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.96}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11.03} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.82}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16.08} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.62}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{20.87} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.36}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{40} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{21.92} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.16}       \\ \cline{2-17} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Iterative}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{34} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.96}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11.03} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.82}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16.00} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.62}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{37} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{20.71} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.30}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{43} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{21.58} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.16}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}           \\ \hline
                                                         &                                                         &                         &                           &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

EDIT1:
My preamble is:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this


%\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage[draft]{todonotes}


\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
```

Comment: Please can you make your code so we can compile it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  can make some column heads two-lined, with the `makecell` package. I took the opportunity to give some vertical padding to the table, and simplified your code, keeping only the necessary `\multicolumn`s. Loading the `caption` package makes the vertical (?) spacing between caption and table more sensible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers'
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this


%\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage[draft]{todonotes}


\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}%graphicx
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering \makegapedcells%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{17}{c|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}[-1.5ex]{Algorithm} & \multirowcell{3}[-1.5ex]{Prediction\\ Method} & \multicolumn{15}{c|}{PH (min)} \\
    \cline{3-17}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{10} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{20} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{30} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{45} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{60} \\
    \cline{3-17}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & W & RMSE & $R_\text{adj}^2$ & W & RMSE & $R_\text{adj}^2$ & W & RMSE & $R_\text{adj}^2$ & W & RMSE & $R_\text{adj}^2$ & W & RMSE & Adj.~$r^2$ \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Naive} & --- & 49 & 7.43 & 0.90 & 49 & 13.40 & 0.69 & 49 & 17.82 & 0.45 & 49 & 21.53 & 0.16 & 49 & 22.75 & 0.00 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirowcell{2}{Linear \\ Regression}} & Direct & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96 & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82 & 19 & 16.08 & 0.62 & 16 & 20.87 & 0.36 & 40 & 21.92 & 0.16 \\
    \cline{2-17}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Iterative & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96 & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82 & 19 & 16.00 & 0.62 & 37 & 20.71 & 0.30 & 43 & 21.58 & 0.16 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirowcell{2}{SVR}} & Direct & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \cline{2-17}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Iterative & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong with the code and I can't understand what it is (I'm still a noob on this).

Comment: What do you mean? You can't compile? Or it doesn't correspond to what you have in mind?

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't compile. I've corrected what I think was the mistake. Could you check that it is what you meant? My output looks like the picture you posted.

Comment: From what I understand from your code it seems that you put the other word (for example, Regression) on the cell bellow Linear. Is it correct? If so, I think that it won't work for me as I'll have an cell on column A with just a small word that groups 2 cells on column B (like the linear regression row). Maybe what I need is to merge the 2 cells on column A. What do you think?

Comment: Your correction is  fine. Thank you. It was a problem with my editor at the time I copied the code to post it. For the placement of regression, it is not exactly on cell below linear: it's the `makecell` version of `\multirow`, which allows for line breaks. I put this multirow on the second row because I thought on first row, there was too much blank space . But if you have some text to put, it's different. Could you post a sample of what you intend to put? I'm not sure I understand very well.

Comment: Could you insert on column A for example SVR and then in column B Direct and Iterative just like I have done for the linear regression row. Also when I try your code in my doc I'm getting some errors. I copied the packages that were missing but it did not solve. 

! LaTeX Error: Command \thead already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ... {\let\tabg@pe\theadgape\thead@}}

Comment: What is your preamble? Your error message seems to correspond to `makecell` being loaded twice, or you defined on your own a `\thead` command, which is already defined by `makecell`.

Comment: @user25847: I've just updated my code, with the additions. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Bernard No, insert bellow Linear Regression. It is the same thing as Linear Regression but on column A is SVR and the values will be different. I also updated the post with the preamble.

Comment: Updated answer. Is that OK?

Comment: Just 2 more things: 1) Could you merge the Algorithm's cell with the one bellow and make the same thing with Prediction Method's cell? 2) Help me with the error that I have when I try to integrate it in my doc. The preamble is on the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25300/discussion-between-bernard-and-user25847).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using `booktabs` which follows at least some (though not all) of the recommendations it makes. This does not exceed the width (`\textheight`) available.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{*{17}{c}}
      \toprule
      \multirow{3}{*}{Algorithm}  & \multirow{3}{.075\textwidth}{\centering Prediction\newline Method} & \multicolumn{15}{c}{PH (min)}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\\cmidrule{3-17}
      & & & 10& & &20& & &30& & &45& & &60&\\ \cmidrule{3-17}
      & & W  & RMSE & $R_{adj}^2$ & W  & RMSE  & $R_{adj}^2$ & W  & RMSE  & $R_{adj}^2$ & W  & RMSE  & $R_{adj}^2$ & W  & RMSE  & Adj.\thinspace $r^2$ \\ \midrule
      Naive  &  & 49 & 7.43 & 0.90 & 49 & 13.40 & 0.69 & 49 & 17.82 & 0.45 & 49 & 21.53 & 0.16  & 49 & 22.75 & 0.00       \\\cmidrule{1-17}
      \multirow{2}{.0775\textwidth}{\centering Linear\newline Regression} & Direct & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96 & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82  & 19 & 16.08 & 0.62  & 16 & 20.87 & 0.36  & 40 & 21.92 & 0.16       \\ \cmidrule{2-17}
      & Iterative                          & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96        & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82        & 19 & 16.00 & 0.62        & 37 & 20.71 & 0.30        & 43 & 21.58 & 0.16       \\\cmidrule{1-17}
      &                                    &    &      &             &    &       &             &    &       &             &    &       &             &    &       &            \\\cmidrule{1-17}
      &                                                         &                         &                           &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                  &                         &                            &                                 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: sideways tabular with <code>booktabs</code>]

Comment: Could you put all the lines around the cells? Thanks. Normally I would accept exactly as you have but I have to present this and they don't want the table like that.

Comment: I mean put also the vertical lines ...

Comment: @user25847 Then you should use Bernard's solution, I think. `booktabs` doesn't work well with vertical lines. It is ideologically opposed to them.

Comment: @user25847 The thing is that reverting to a standard layout and adding the vertical rules back in makes my solution exceed the available space. I immediately get overfull boxes again. Since I'd already trimmed stuff to make it fit, this doesn't leave many options. You can reduce the horizontal spacing between columns but the table will be even less readable (the loss of vertical spacing already makes it somewhat less readable) or you can reduce the font size which will also make it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the game, but hopefully still useful.

Note that all `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` wrappers are gone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs}
%% macro for a "small", i.e., compressed table
\newcommand\smtab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{15}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Algorithm &
\smtab{Prediction\\ Method} & \multicolumn{15}{c}{PH (min)} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){3-17} 
&  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{10} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{20} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{30}
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{45} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{60} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-11} \cmidrule(lr){12-14} \cmidrule(l){15-17}  
& & W & RMSE & $R_{\textit{adj}}^2$
  & W & RMSE & $R_{\textit{adj}}^2$ 
  & W & RMSE & $R_{\textit{adj}}^2$ 
  & W & RMSE & $R_{\textit{adj}}^2$ 
  & W & RMSE & $R_{\textit{adj}}^2$ \\
\midrule
Naive & -- & 49 & 7.43 & 0.90 & 49 & 13.40 & 0.69 & 49 & 17.82 & 0.45        & 49 & 21.53 & 0.16        & 49 & 22.75 & 0.00       \\ \addlinespace
Lin.\ Regr. & Direct                             & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96        & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82        & 19 & 16.08 & 0.62        & 16 & 20.87 & 0.36        & 40 & 21.92 & 0.16       \\ 
 & Iterative                          & 34 & 5.10 & 0.96        & 19 & 11.03 & 0.82        & 19 & 16.00 & 0.62        & 37 & 20.71 & 0.30        & 43 & 21.58 & 0.16       \\ 
\\ 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```